# Adding same precision to the yAxis Label of HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to format the yAxis label and add trailing zeros after decimal. The number of precision will be decided dynamically as per the value of yAxis labels.

For Example: If there are 3 labels in yAxis with value 95.8, 95.825, and 95.85. then, it should be displayed as 95.800, 95.825, 95.850.

**Edit**:
Actually, the requirement is to have the decimal precision dynamically. Actually sometimes, our chart shows labels as 93,94,95, in this case we don't want to add precision. The idea is to add same precision, if the chart is generating, yAxis labels like 94.25, 94.5, 94.75, then, I want the chart to show yAxis labels as 94.24, 94.50, 94.75.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dataLabels there are some format parameters you can add to your y values.

**You can add this to the `plotOptions` structure like this:**

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{y:.3f}' // <<< .3f is 3 decimal places out.
        }
    }
},
```

**Here is a modified fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ja799vep/

**More details from highcharts.com:**

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry the example above was just for datalabels...Here is an **improved example** that shows, xAxis, yAxis, dataLables and toolTip with different '3 decimal place' approaches.

http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/okce7p7n/

Comment: loop through the data and find the maximum of decimal places, then set format correctly, example here http://jsfiddle.net/ja799vep/1/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but my question is to format yAxis labels not DataLabels.

Comment: Accepting the answer as it will solve other's problem that would be generic for highchart yAxis DataLabel.

Comment: @kundankumar I have updated an example with several approaches and targeting several different chart targets (xAxis, yAxix, toolTip, datalables). Please review my answer for an updated jsFiddle example.